# Convergence of the integral of $x\sin(x^p)$ from $0$ to $+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

> Let $p\in \mathbb{R}, p>0$ for which values of $p$ does the following integral converge?
> $$\int_0^{\infty}x\sin(x^p)dx $$

I'm not sure how I can go about this question, I know that simply trying to come up with a closed form for the integral becomes difficult very quickly. I also know that it diverges when $p \in (0,2)$ from intuition I suspect that it converges when $p>1$ but I don't know how I should proceed.

Comment: I suggest making a change of variables first $t=x^p$.

Comment: How can it converge for all $p>1$ if it diverges for all $p\in(0,\,2)$? I recommend a sector contour, angle $\pi/(2p)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $x \mapsto x^{\frac{1}{p}}$ to find that your integral is
$$\frac{1}{p}\int_0^\infty x^{2/p-1}\sin(x)\,dx.$$
There is no problem near $x=0$. To make sure that the integral converges at infinity, we need $1-\frac{2}{p}>0$, *i.e.* $p>2$.

Comment: The other possibility could be $p<-2$, I have checked it numerically.

Comment: The OP stated that $p>0$ …

Comment: The result of integration is really nice. By the way (+1)